# ^M^Mtypedef enum - Stray characters in Header file

Tags: c

I am using Vim editor and when I open the my file, I get some stray characters as shown below:

```
^M^Mtypedef enum
```

This is not giving any compilation problem. But it looks absurd while I look at code.

Before I deliver the code, I want to remove these stray characters. Please suggest a way.

**Additional INFO:**

When I am using source insight to open the files, the special characters are not displayed, but the the colours of the variables are being shown wrong, e.g. for an `enum` type variable, generally source insight shows blue, but because of these stray chars, which are shown as a space, the colour is being shown as green. If I remove the extra space (actually an ^M,) the colour is properly displayed.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C but with the environement you are using. Please tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dos2unix as suggested by most, did not work for me. Finally i did a simple thing. Copied the whle code, pasted inside a text file. Copied it from there once agin and replaced it again in my source code. This did work..!!

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of them them with the substitute command in vim:

```
:%s/^V^M//g
```

`^V^M` means: type Control+v - hold down the Control key and type `v`, then Control+m.

Comment: It says E486: Pattern not found: ^V^M

Answer (score 1):

Pls use the follwoing command.

```
dos2unix *
```

This will remove those special chars.

Answer (score 1):

^M is a DOS Line Break Character which shows up in Linux, if you download a file from Windows.

Try the below:

```
:%s/(ctrl+v)(ctrl+m)//g
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace \r with \n. Try sed. ^M is actually \r